# Reverse proxy not rewriting location after redirect

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have an apache reverse proxy set up like this:

```
<Location /test>
  ProxyPass https://exampleUrl.com retry=0 ttl=50
  ProxyPassReverse https://exampleUrl.com
</Location>
```

I'm sending a token to login with my request to https://localUrl/test/login.php?token=
I get redirected by the remote server and the reverse proxy rewrites the location properly to: /test/sso.php?id=61127
my request to /test/sso.php?id=61127 gets redirected again but this time the location is not rewritten properly: /status/sso.php 
So it tries to find the resource on my own server while it should point to the proxy: /test/status/sso.php

What am I doing wrong, why is the second redirect location not rewritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should need to match slashes in the ProxyPass directive, always, that is, in this case:`https://exampleUrl should be https://exampleUrl/` because that's what it is, and you should do the same in the ProxyPassReverse directive.

In any case, better examine the replies from the backend adding the following to the LogFormat you are using:

```
%{Location}o
```

It will print whatever location is the backend sending and help you understand what is going wrong, if matching slashes doesn't solve your issue in case it is your backend sending a /status/ for which you are not proxying.